# Matlab: Count till sum equals 360 > insert event1, next 360 >insert event 2 etc

Tags: matlab, if-statement, sum

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while now and I would appreciate a push in the right direction.

I have a matrix called Turn. This matrix contains 1 column of data, somewhere between 10000 and 15000 rows (is variable). What I like to do is as follows:
start at row 1 and add values of row 2, row 3 etc till sum==360. When sum==360 insert in column 2 at that specific row 'event 1'. 
Start counting at the next row (after 'event 1') till sum==360. When sum==360 insert in column 2 at that specific row 'event 2'. etc

So I basically want to group my data in partitions of sum==360 
these will be called events.

The row number at which sum==360 is important to me as well (every row is a time point so it will tells me the duration of an event). I want to put those row numbers in a new matrix in which on row 1: rownr event 1 happened, row 2: rownr event 2 happened etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the row indices where events occur using the following code.  Basically you're going to use the modulo operator to find where the sum of the first column of `Turn` is a multiple of 360.

```
mod360 = mod(cumsum(Turn(:,1)),360);
eventInds = find(mod360 == 0);
```

You could then loop over `eventInds` to place whatever values you'd like in the appropriate rows in the second column of `Turn`.

I don't think you'll be able to place the string 'event 1' in the column though as a string array is acts like a vector and will result in a dimension mismatch.  You could just store the numerical value `1` for the first event and `2` for the second event and so on.

Comment: so in the mod360 matrix I find the instances when it reached 360? 
a numerical number for event would be fine as well

Comment: Clever use of modulo arithmetic to find the indices. +1

Comment: `mod360` will contain the remainder of your cumulative sum divided by 360.  So everywhere `mod360` contains a zero means that the cumulative sum of your first column was a multiple of 360.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan's answer looks like the way to go. But if your condition is such that you need to find row numbers where the cumulative sum is not exactly 360, then you would be required to do a little more work. For that case, you may use this -

Try this vectorized (and no loops) code to get the row IDs where the 360 grouping occurs -

```
threshold = 360;
cumsum_val = cumsum(Turn);
ind1 = find(cumsum_val>=threshold,1)
num_events = floor(cumsum_val(end)/threshold);
[x1,y1] = find(bsxfun(@gt,cumsum_val,threshold.*(1:num_events)));
[~,b,~] = unique(y1,'first');
row_nums = x1(b)
```

After that you can get the  event data, like this -

```
event1 = Turn(1:row_nums(1));
event2 = Turn(row_nums(1)+1:row_nums(2));
event3 = Turn(row_nums(2)+1:row_nums(3));
...
event21 = Turn(row_nums(20)+1:row_nums(21));

...
eventN = Turn(row_nums(N-1)+1:row_nums(N));
```

**Edit 1**

**Sample case:**

We create a small data of `20` random integer numbers instead of `15000` as used for the original problem. Also, we are using a threshold of `30` instead of `360` to account for the small datasize.

**Code**

```
Turn = randi(10,[20 1]);
threshold = 30;

cumsum_val = cumsum(Turn);
ind1 = find(cumsum_val>=threshold,1)
num_events = floor(cumsum_val(end)/threshold);
[x1,y1] = find(bsxfun(@gt,cumsum_val,threshold.*(1:num_events)));
[~,b,~] = unique(y1,'first');
row_nums = x1(b);
```

**Run**

```
Turn =

     7
     6
     3
     4
     5
     3
     9
     2
     3
     2
     3
     5
     4
    10
     5
     2
    10
    10
     5
     2


threshold =

    30


row_nums =

     7
    14
    18
```

The run results shows the `row_nums` as `7, 14, 18`, which mean that the second grouping starts with the 7th index in `Turn`, third grouping starts at 14th index and so on. Of course, you can append `1` at the beginning of `row_nums` to indicate that the first grouping starts at the 1st index.

Comment: I tried this approach and it works partly. The amount of events is correct, however the row_nums is giving 8 times 1

Comment: @user3462307 `row_nums` is basically a vector of row indices of `Turn`,  where each such 360 grouping starts. Read more about it at the Edit 1 section above.

Answer (score 0):

Given a column vector `x`, say,

```
x = randi(100,10,1)
```

the following would give you the index of the first row where the cumulative sum off all the items above that row adds up to 360:

```
i = max( find( cumsum(x) <= 360) )
```

Then, you would have to use that index to find the next set of cumulative sums that add up to 360, something like

```
offset = max( find( cumsum(x(i+1:end)) <= 360 ) )
i_new = i + offset
```

You might need to add +1/-1 to the offset and the index.

```
>> x = randi(100,10,1)'
x =
  90    47    47    44     8    79    45     9    91     6

>> cumsum(x)
ans =
  90   137   184   228   236   315   360   369   460   466

>> i = max(find(cumsum(x)<=360))
i =
  7
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply.
I tried that before but it did not work. It basically gives the last row number (in this case 15550) while at row 10 value 360 is indicated. So i should be row 10

Comment: You must have made a mistake. The above code should work. See my result posted in the answer.

Comment: dont know what it was but you are right, the first part now works.

Comment: You would have to write a for loop, where initially `offset=0`. In the for loop compute `i`, compute the `offset` and add it to `i` to compute its new value in the next iteration, and so on.